# .Net 8 Function App doesn't load functions from dependencies

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, .net-8.0

I have a solution with 2 projects, both are Function Apps (Targetframework: net8.0, AzureFunctionsVersion: v4, FunctionsInDependencies: true, function process model: isolated).
[.Net 8.0 solution setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gad0c.png)

The 1st project (FunctionApp2) has no Function in it (Function2.cs has just commented code) and is used to spin up Functions from the referenced projects (FunctionAppNet8). The problem is, that the functions are not loaded from the dependencies until I implement and start a function in the 1st project (Function2.cs). The 2 projects have an active dependency: the Program.cs creates and instance of a dummy class from the referenced project.

I have a similar setup with .Net 6, in-process  model, where a similar project configuration loads the functions from the dependencies. The active reference between the projects is implemented through inheritance of the Startup.cs classes.
[.Net 6.0 solution setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3sPa.png)

I tried with .Net 8.0:

- Add an active dependency between the projects (see above) => no effect until the 1st project implements a function.
- Split the 2 projects (no reference) and add the job from the 2nd into the 1st as a link. Add any missing functionality and other references as required. Idea from here: [Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59170087/is-there-a-way-to-have-an-azure-function-app-created-from-multiple-net-projects) Although this works, look a bit like a workaround.

I expect, that the functions from the dependencies are loaded through the `<FunctionsInDependencies>true</FunctionsInDependencies>` setting.

Source code:

[.Net 6 solution as reference](https://github.com/GergelyGlasz/FunctionAppNet6)

[.Net 8 solution with the problem](https://github.com/GergelyGlasz/FunctionAppNet8)

Comment: please share your function code?

Comment: please share you `.csproj` file

Comment: Source coded uploaded to GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `.NET 8` solution `<FunctionsInDependencies>` is not set to true in `FunctionApp2.csproj`

I am able to load function from dependencies.

- Make sure you have added `<FunctionsInDependencies>`and set it `true` and  `<ProjectReference>` is set to the path of the reference function's `.csproj` file in your main Function's `.csproj` file. In my Function solution its `FunctionApp3.csproj` file.

  ```
  <FunctionsInDependencies>true</FunctionsInDependencies>
  ```

  ```
  <ProjectReference Include="..\FunctionAppNet3\FunctionAppNet3.csproj" />`
  ```

This Worked for me.

**#My Directory :**

```
MyFunctionAppSolution/
│
├── FunctionApp3/                  <-- Main function to run which will call <Function1.cs> http  trigger
│   ├── FunctionApp3.csproj
│   ├── FunctionApp3.cs            <--Empty file    
│   ├── Program.cs
│   ├── local.settings.json                
│   └── host.json              
│
└── FunctionAppNet3/              
    ├── FunctionAppNet3.csproj
    ├── Function1.cs              <-- Http trigger function
    ├── Program.cs
    ├── Local.settings.json              
    └── host.json
```

[image]

**`FunctionApp3.csproj`:**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
      <FunctionsInDependencies>true</FunctionsInDependencies>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\FunctionAppNet3\FunctionAppNet3.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`FunctionAppNet3.csproj`:** (default- no changes)

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.20.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http.AspNetCore" Version="1.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.ApplicationInsights" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**`Function1.cs`:**

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionAppNet3
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions! from FunctionAppNet3");
        }
    }
}
```

## `OUTPUT`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the example. I uploaded the correct version. The fixes:
- .csproj fixed with <FunctionsInDependencies>true</FunctionsInDependencies>
- .csproj has the project reference
- .functions configuration is corrected

Comment: The NOT WORKING solution uses the NuGet Pacakge:
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.17.0" />

If I downgrade (don't update to the latest) to the "default", that is used by creating a new project, the functions are found as expected.
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.16.40" />

Comment: @GergelyGlász I am able to execute functions without any issues with latest version too.
[FunctionApp3.csproj](https://i.imgur.com/YC4EJie.png), [FunctionAppNet3.csproj](https://i.imgur.com/73Euv1m.png) [execution](https://i.imgur.com/25rq9qG.png) [output](https://i.imgur.com/Bhfb2Jq.png)

Comment: Can you try it again with a QueueTrigger function as well? TimerTrigger works with v1.17.1 for me as well, but the QueueTrigger still doesn't. I reported the issue on the projects/packages GutHub page.

Comment: @GergelyGlász I tried Queue trigger with All other Packages with latest versions and `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk` with `v1.17.1` and I found that I am getting [error](https://i.imgur.com/jKf9RJL.png), with `v1.17.0` sometimes its working [fine](https://i.imgur.com/R3IWL95.png) and sometimes its throwing [error](https://i.imgur.com/DoNNG6n.png). with `v1.16.4` its working fine without any issues

Comment: I have also raise issue in [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2309)

Comment: @GergelyGlász I would suggest Please Use v1.16.4

Comment: @GergelyGlász I was informed in my raised [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/2309) to use `v1.17.2`, I used and it fixed the issue. Use `v1.17.2`. I hope it resolves your issue too.

Comment: @Vaibhav Shandilya Thanks, v.1.17.2 works for me as well..